# how to sum values entered by textbox in listbox?

Tags: vb.net

I have a listbox1 and a textbox1, textbox2 and textbox3. I am trying to add all values in first row when transferred from textbox1 and add all values in second row when transferred from textbox2. For example if I pass 500 two times in listbox it should add that two 500 and becomes 1000 in listbox1 and display like items 1000. Same thing for textbox2. And total of values of textbox1 and textbox 2 should be show in textbox3.

My code is here

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then Exit Sub

If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim sum As Double
    For x As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        sum += CDbl(ListBox1.Items(x))

    Next
    TextBox3.Text = sum
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End If
```

Comment: What isn't working? Does the code get called? Is the current sum incorrect?

Comment: Code works.  Show your event handler.  Put Option Strict On at the top of your code file.

Comment: code works but did not sum value in lisbox.

Comment: I tried this code in keyup event of textbox1 and worked fine.

Comment: "For example if I pass 500 two times in listbox it should add that two 500 and becomes 1000 in listbox1 and display like items 1000" - what???

Comment: @Enigmativity it adds 500 two times in listbox1 and shows 1000 in textbox3. and the code must do that, Because the code written for it.

Comment: @isaeid - It's very unclear: "becomes 1000 in listbox1" & "display like items 1000". It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Enigmativity, No, 1000 not became in listbox1, the code shows 500 in listbox1 two times, and the sum of two 500 is 1000 and shows the result(1000) in textbox3.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in keyup event of textbox1 and worked fine. 
But i suggest to you, instead of your for loop, you can use linq query like this:

```
 TextBox3.Text =   (From m In ListBox1.Items
                    Select CDbl(m)).Sum
```

I think this is faster way to sum a collection of items.

Comment: Does this compile? `ListBox1.Items` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Only must be sure the system.linq namespace is added to project. i tried  the code and it runs fine. You can try yourself.

Comment: I did try and it failed. Are you using `Option Strict On`?